# StringSize returns wrong height for text more than two lines

Tags: c#, ios, uilabel

Here is the method that I am using it returns wrong height for text more than two lines. so I am getting dots in the label.
According to documentation its supposed to work

```
public CGSize sizeForString(String str, UIFont fnt,CGRect rectTxt)
        {
            UILabel lbl = new UILabel();
            lbl.Frame = rectTxt;
            lbl.Font = fnt;
            lbl.Text = str;
            return lbl.Text.StringSize(lbl.Font, new CGSize(rectTxt.Width,200), UILineBreakMode.WordWrap);
        }
```

Any help is appreciated !

Comment: What language is that?

Comment: This is C sharp ... in Objective c also results are same

Comment: @matt - if there is a better way to find size of string for label ... you can answer me If it works I will accept it as answer

Comment: I don't know C# so I can't help. I don't even understand, from your code, what the givens are and what the problem is. The label will automatically size itself to the text or will cut off the text by using dots, depending on how you configure it; so what's the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: calculating the size of drawn text is very difficult.  Take the strings "Y" and "y" and "Yy".  Do you expect the height of each to be calculated the as the same answer?  This question is not as simple as you make it out to be.  What is your input?  What answer are you getting?  What answer are you expecting?

Comment: Did you set the correct fontsize of fnt?

Comment: Are you trying to find the height of the font? That is a very simple task. You can just call fnt.Height. That will return the height of the font. You could also create a Graphics object and call Graphics.MeasureString().Height.

Comment: Basically I want to increase the height of the label according to the content and I don't want the text to be clipped... so I am using the above function to calculate the height of text on label and changing the label heights dynamically to accomodate it

Comment: in my finding it doesn't work if the font size is 15 but it works if the font size is 17